# Копирование нескольких файлов через командную строку в windows

Tags: windows, cmd, файловая-система

На linux скопировать, скажем два файла, можно с помощью команды `cp` просто написав эти файлы через пробел и прописав путь куда эти они копируются. 
Пример: `cp file1.txt index.html C:\new_folder`

А как это сделать в `cmd` windows?
Команда `copy` копирует один файл, а два файла записанные через пробел вызывают ошибку.

Как это можно сделать? Как должна выглядеть такая команда?

Comment: Проблему решил прокачкой cmd и добавлением в нее linux команд (воспользовался статьей с хабра http://habrahabr.ru/post/177033/ )  c помощью программы clink    https://mridgers.github.io/clink/    и  программы UnxUtils   http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/

Comment: Теперь    cp file1.txt index.html C:\new_folder    работает и в cmd. Может  кому пригодиться решение. Если тяжело осваивать cmd.

Comment: От команд robocopy и for %I   %I успешного результата не добился.

Comment: именно с тем функционалом, о котором вы спрашивали в вопросе, robocopy вполне справляется являясь средством "из коробки".

Comment: Проверил robocopy еще раз - работает. Спасибо:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться командой `robocopy`. Больше примеров есть [тут.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/922607/2546083) Пример использования:

`robocopy source\folder dest\folder file1.txt index.html`

Answer (score 8):

В Windows есть [PowerShell](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) -- оболочка с интерфейсом командной строки и сопутствующего языка сценариев. Копировать файл можно так

```
Copy-Item c:\scripts\test.txt c:\test
```

Копировать папку с файлами и всеми подпапками так

```
Copy-Item c:\scripts c:\test -recurse
```

у Copy-Item есть alias'ы: cpi, cp, copy
Описание [тут](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx).

Comment: интересно, `ps` сделан в угоду люниксоидам?

Comment: @MatthewHaig _"ps сделан в угоду люниксоидам?"_ -- наверное просто сделали для администраторов. есть же wmi, но надо знать язык программирования, чтобы его использовать. изучать целый язык, чтобы что-то сделать - не хотели. а с командами и сценариями разобрались и используют.

Comment: Видимо так и есть

Answer (score 1):

В 2016 году для запуска UNIX-команд и утилит в Windows [рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35665124/5951529) воспользоваться [Cash](https://github.com/dthree/cash).

- Быстрая установка,
- Команды точно такие же, как и на UNIX-подобных ОС, не нужно переучиваться,
- Возможность комбинирования команд различных операционных систем.

Устанавливаем [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), если ещё нет, → в командной строке Windows вводим `npm install cash-global -g` → ждём, пока установится, → тестируем команды для Linux прямо там же, в `Cmd.exe`. [Список поддерживаемых Cash команд](https://github.com/dthree/cash#supported-commands), [небольшой обзор Cash на русском языке](http://losst.ru/kak-vypolnit-linux-komandu-iz-windows).

Чтобы применять команды `alias`, `clear`, `export`, `false`, `kill`, `source`, `true` и `unalias` на август 2016 потребуется предварительно вводить `cash`, пример:

```
E:\Киролайна>alias sl=ls
"alias" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

E:\Киролайна>cash
SashaGoddess@DESKTOP-0G54NVG:E/Киролайна$ alias sl=ls
SashaGoddess@DESKTOP-0G54NVG:E/Киролайна$
```

Все остальные поддерживаемые команды работают и без `cash`. Для копирования нескольких файлов после установки Cash достаточно ввести в интерпретатор командной строки то же самое: `cp file1.txt index.html C:\new_folder`.

Comment: Комментруйте минусы, пожалуйста, кто ставит. Это работает, условиям вопроса (а как это сделать в `cmd` Windows?) отвечает. Спасибо.